# Android で再生中の曲の情報を取得したい

Tags: android

Android で曲の情報を取得したいのですが, どうやって再生中の曲の情報を取得すればよいか分かりません. どのようなコードでやっていけばよいか教えてください.

Comment: "再生中”というのは自前アプリ／他アプリでの再生ですか？"曲の情報"とは具体的に何を指しますか？

Comment: 他の音楽プレイヤーアプリ(Apple music, play music など) から, 曲のタイトル, シングル(アルバム)タイトル, アーティスト名を取得したいです

Answer (score 4):

「任意のPlayer」の再生している楽曲情報を取得するのはアプリケーションからは不可能と思います。

「特定のPlayer」で言いますと
Google Play Music(com.android.music)はBroadcastにて以下のActionをフィルタすることで確認できます。

```
* "com.android.music.metachanged"
* "com.android.music.queuechanged",
* "com.android.music.playbackcomplete"
* "com.android.music.playstatechanged"
```

getStringExtraにて取得できる情報は以下です。

```
* "id" - Integer: the database row ID
* "artist" - String: the name of the artist
* "album" - String: the name of the album
* "track" - String: the name of the track
* The intent has an action that is one of
```

参考：https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/master/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java